# How does the eks worker node get ecr login?

Tags: amazon-eks, amazon-ecr

We need get login when operate ecr, like `"aws ecr get-login-password --region ap-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin xxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com"`. but I found eks worker node can  pull image directly. why? The node run this command automatically in somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

yes, ECR is integrated with EKS and ECS which allows them to pull images from your registry given that the worker node IAM role has certain permissions. you can find the list of required permissions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ECR_on_EKS.html)

Comment: thank Reza, even i assign ecr full access to an ec2 machine, then pull image, still need run get-login command, the ec2 machine linked same role as eks worker. i want to know why the eks worker don't need that.

Answer (score 0):

kubelet seems to try to generate ECR token if EC2 related files exist or credentials can be fetched. Please refer ec2ValidationImpl and isEC2 in below code.

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/542829d30d2e48abb802e4f4499dc63dd8076c3d/pkg/credentialprovider/aws/aws_credentials.go#L91-L144

And generated token is added to dockerconfig cache in kubelet.

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/542829d30d2e48abb802e4f4499dc63dd8076c3d/pkg/credentialprovider/aws/aws_credentials.go#L211-L241

I guess these configurations enable to pull ECR image without any auth in kubelet.

Comment: Seem make sense.